# Scheme language: #void error output

Tags: list, scheme, void, display

This is my program:

```
(define (listof n m)
(display " ( ")
(let loop ((times n))

   (if (= times 0)
     (display ") ")
     (begin (display m)
            (display " ")
            (loop (- times 1))))))

=> (listof 2 (listof 2 2))
```

Expected output:        `((2 2) (2 2))` .
Output received:   `( 2 2 )  ( # < void> # < void> )`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the function supposed to produce a list, or print things surrounded by parentheses? (The `#<void>`s are the values produced by `display`.)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the listof function is #< void >.
This is because the last thing that is done is `(display ") ")`.
This prints ") " to standard output, but doesn't return a meaningful value to the calling function (hence #< void >). This means that you can't nest calls to listof in this way.

So in other words, to fix this, you have to make the function return a meaningful value. You could construct a string with string-append for example. I'm assuming you don't want to construct actual lists here, otherwise you should look into how lists work.

Here's an example (this one only works with strings):

```
(define (listof n m)
   (let loop ((times n) (res "("))

      (if (= times 0)
         (string-append res " )")
         (loop (- times 1) (string-append res " " m)))))



> (listof 3 (listof 2 "hello"))
"( ( hello hello ) ( hello hello ) ( hello hello ) )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `(listof 2 (listof 2 2))` i supposed to output `((2 2) (2 2))` I'm pretty sure you must make code that produces the list and it has **nothing to do with printing**. Thus you cannot use `display`.

Why? Well. Imagine if `(listof 2 2)` should print "(2 2)" it is obvious that the return is no consequence. Thus the same output as `display` is ok. Thus `(listof 2 (listof 2 2))` should display `(2 2) (? ?)` where `?` is whatever what `listof` returns.

If `listof` should return a list with the passed argument then `(listof 2 2)` should **return** `(cons 2 (cons 2 '())`. You need to rewrite your procedure such that it does that instead.